# Force click with trigger() on closest div

Tags: jquery, html, triggers, click

Hi I've got follow code:

```js
$('.myInput').click(function() {
  $('.addon').trigger('click');
});

$('.addon').click(function() {
  console.log("Clicked");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inputWithAddon {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input {
  height: 20px;
}
.addon {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input class="myInput">
    <div class="addon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input class="myInput">
    <div class="addon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input class="myInput">
    <div class="addon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to force a click with `trigger()` on my green div, when I clicked in the input. This should be on the div from the current clicked input (on the right side). At the moment, it calls the click for all the green divs (look at console). I would like just to do this for the div of the clicked input. I tried `closest()`:

```
$(this).closest('.addon').trigger('click');
```

It didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What is problem? See https://jsfiddle.net/cho912xp/

Comment: @Mohammad This is confusing?! Have you seen my code snippet in the question? When you click on one input, it prints 3 times the "clicked", for each green div. I have the same problem in my web application. In fiddle it seems to work?!

Comment: @Mohammad but wait, that's not the same code like mine... You added siblings() to the trigger, this seems to work.

Comment: @MrBuggy look at layout independant soln. if that you might change the html later.

Comment: @Iceman Hallo and thanks for the cool answer. It works fine. I marked the first answer with the sibling as correct, he was first and the solution is good, so I think it's fair and correct to give him the mark. Thanks again.

Comment: @MrBuggy no worries with the accepting. just mentioned so that you noticed the layout-dep. thats all. infact this layout indep soln  was proposed by freedomn-m

Comment: @Iceman Yes I saw it, it's superb thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the sibling property of Jquery

```
$(this).siblings('.addon').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!! I will mark it as correct as soon as possible! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A possible soln would be:

```
$(this).parent().find('.addon').trigger('click');
```

or as `@Mohammad` mentioned shortest:

```
$(this).next().trigger('click');
```

or as `@Deepak Singh` answered:

```
$(this).siblings('.addon').click();
```

or as `@freedomn-m` mentioned a (more) layout independant solution:

```
$(this).closest(".inputWithAddon").find(".addon").click();
```

```js
$('.myInput').click(function() {
  $(this).next().trigger('click');
});

$('.addon').click(function() {
  console.log("Clicked");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inputWithAddon {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input {
  height: 20px;
}
.addon {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input class="myInput">
    <div class="addon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input class="myInput">
    <div class="addon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input class="myInput">
    <div class="addon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `parent().find('.addon')` do work of `siblings('.addon')`

Comment: You can use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) instead that select next sibling of input.

Comment: @Mohammad amazing, i wasn't aware of so many alternatives. added it too. more the merrier.

Comment: Ok, then you should add:  `$(this).closest(".inputWithAddon").find(".addon").click();` as all the others are too closely tied to the *specific* html layout and (the others) will be more likely to break if any changes are made to the layout/structure.

Comment: @freedomn-m added the layout independant soln, and credited :D

Comment: The only truly layout-independent version would be to pair each input with it's div via `data-` attributes.

Comment: I agree, infact you could easily throw in id's from a templater engine easily and catch faster using the id too with more accuracy.

Comment: Please look at my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303468/trigger-click-on-closest-div-with-angularjs  I try the same with angular and I have problems...