# Trigger click on closest div with angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, triggers, click

Hi I've got follow code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.clickedInput = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      angular.element('.addon').triggerHandler('click');
    }, 100);
  }

  $scope.clickedAddon = function(number) {
    console.log(number);
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inputWithAddon {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input {
  height: 20px;
}
.addon {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input placeholder="1" class="myInput" ng-click="clickedInput()">
    <div class="addon" ng-click="clickedAddon(1)">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input placeholder="2" class="myInput" ng-click="clickedInput()">
    <div class="addon" ng-click="clickedAddon(2)">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input placeholder="3" class="myInput" ng-click="clickedInput()">
    <div class="addon" ng-click="clickedAddon(3)">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My idea is, when I click in an input, it forces a click with `triggerHandler()` to the green div on the right side and prints his number. It should just force the click of the green div, which is on the right side of the clicked input, not all of them. I wrote today a similar question for JQuery: [Force click with trigger() on closest div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302447/force-click-with-trigger-on-closest-div?noredirect=1#comment64022680_38302447)

There it works fine with more possible solutions. How can I do the same effect with angularjs?

Thanks.

Comment: in angular you should just directly change the function in the ng-click, much cleaner. "think-angular" "not-think-jquery"

Comment: The problem is, that my addon button calls a tooltip with a costum attribut and some json data within... It's a plugin and handles the tooltip in the background. So I have to force a click on it. This is just a example to show the effect.. I can't just call a function in my real code for the addon...

Comment: Done!!! chk my answer. 1/2 an hour of painstacking puzzle work clearly shows why we all need jquery. :D

Comment: Run the snippet and confirm this is what you wanted!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `$event` to the main `ng-click function` and then get `.parent()` and then the 2nd child. Then trigger.

```
var a = angular
             .element($event.target)
             .parent().children()
        angular
             .element(a[1]).triggerHandler('click');
```

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.clickedInput = function($event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var a = angular
             .element($event.target)
             .parent().children()
        angular
             .element(a[1]).triggerHandler('click');
        
    }, 100);
  }

  $scope.clickedAddon = function(number) {
    console.log(number);
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inputWithAddon {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input {
  height: 20px;
}
.addon {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input placeholder="1" class="myInput" ng-click="clickedInput($event)">
    <div class="addon" ng-click="clickedAddon(1)">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input placeholder="2" class="myInput" ng-click="clickedInput($event)">
    <div class="addon" ng-click="clickedAddon(2)">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputWithAddon">
    <input placeholder="3" class="myInput" ng-click="clickedInput($event)">
    <div class="addon" ng-click="clickedAddon(3)">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```